# How can I get acube effect app drawer on ICS or JB?

Tags: launcher

This is how my CM7 running phone looks like (although I got the screenshot from somewhere): Is there a similar effect launcher for ICS or JB?

[image: Launcher]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go Launcher, launch the drawer, click Application settings, click App drawer scrolling orientation, set Vertical Continuous or Vertical Loop and then Vertical Waterfall. WIN.

Answer (score 1):

The drawer and its animation effects are part of the Launcher (a.k.a. Home) app.  Stock Launcher in [AOSP](http://source.android.com/) (Android Open Source Project), which CM and many other custom ROMs are based on, hasn't included this particular effect since Honeycomb (Android 3.x).

You can most probably find the app drawer's "cube" scrolling effect in 3rd-party Launcher replacement apps.  I would start [looking](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=launcher%20replacement&c=apps) at Google Play store for various Launcher apps (e.g. [Apex Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher), [AWD.Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adw.launcher), etc.)

Comment: Well, the question is, I guess, did anyone meet this effect in any of the launchers or should I try them all :/ ?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to try them on your own.  There is a reason app-shopping questions are off-topic on this site.  They invite a non-ending list that can (and usually does) get out of date.  You can always skim through Play Store comments, or try looking at the apps' websites or forums for details on the specific feature you're looking for.

Comment: A non ending list containing 0 elements. I see.